# Executing infinite scroll on dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that load content using a MySQL database. And users can filter content using few buttons and then this content get replaced with dynamically pulled data using jQuery. Also the link I use in infinite scroll also change. But infinite scroll plugin seems to only take the same old link and not the newly loaded link to trigger scroll.

jQuery infinity scroll plugin that i use

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.1.0/jquery.infinitescroll.js

This is my code

```
<div class="container" id="myposts">
<div class=”post”>
<p>my content</p>
</div>
</div>

<nav id="page-nav"><a href="myposts.php?page=2"></a></nav>

//jQuery code
$('#myposts').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '. post ',     //
        loading: {
                        finishedMsg: 'End of the page',
                        img: 'images/loader.gif'
    }
    }, function(newElements, data, url){

});
```

I’m changing the scroll trigger link from

```
<nav id="page-nav"><a href="myposts.php?page=2"></a></nav>
```

To

```
<nav id="page-nav"><a href="getposts.php?page=2"></a></nav>
```

But plugin still take the old link to trigger scroll. Is there any solution for this? Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the `append.infiniteScroll` event and then update the link from your page.
https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#append
https://infinite-scroll.com/api.html#option

Something like this:

```
$container.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
  $container.infiniteScroll( 'nextSelector', '#page-nav a' )
});
```